# How to change Android swipe to horizontal for accessibility?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

I'm trying to see a way to make my screen slide horizontally, this screen is built with json data, I use only a fragment, it works like instagram stories, I want to make the content slide horizontally for users who use accessibility, can you help me?

Comment: You should add more detail.

Comment: If you can add any existing code, and describe it's purpose, this is always helpful. Then going a step further, anything you've tried that didn't work. It's really difficult to provide too much information, if the information is relevant. Any examples you can point to are always helpful as well!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding TalkBack, there are two solutions I would recommend:

1. For screen reader users with some sight: They should be able to swipe with two fingers. This bypasses the TalkBack gesture layer
2. For users with no vision: add an [action](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#accessibility-actions) to the container:

[XML-based layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#accessibility-actions):

```
// Do for next and previous
ViewCompat.addAccessibilityAction(
    // View to add accessibility action
    swipeableContainer,
    // Label surfaced to user by an accessibility service
    getText(R.string.next)
) { _, _ ->
    // Same method executed when swiping on itemView
    navigateToNextItem()
    true
}
```

[JetPack compose based](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility#custom-actions) layouts:

```
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = { /* ... */ })
        .semantics {
            // Set any explicit semantic properties
            customActions = listOf(
                CustomAccessibilityAction(actionLabel, navigateToNextItem())
            )
        }
```

The action also helps those who use [Switch Access](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6122836?hl=en-GB) to navigate.

Bonus: Also consider adding some [keyboard actions](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/commands) for those with motor disabilities that can't use gestures or just prefer using a keyboard.

```
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    return when (keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT -> {
            previousItem()
            true
        }
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT -> {
            nextItem()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```